# Dwarf Fortress HUD & LazyNewbPack / PeridexisErrant border and numbers

Tags: dwarf-fortress

This question is almost a duplicate of [What exactly is displayed on the left and right borders of the screen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/what-exactly-is-displayed-on-the-left-and-right-borders-of-the-screen) That question nicely covers most of my HUD questions (I've labeled my question this way to make that question easier to find along with this extra info.)

The LazyNewbPack (now PeridexisErrant) adds one additional info section on the bottom right of the page. Mine currently reads as follows:

H: 1/0/3/1/15/0/0

What are the meanings of those values if we give those sections corresponding letters like this:

H: A/B/C/D/E/F/G

I can only assume that E (15) represents dwarfs. Beyond that, I have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats a happiness meter, each section represents a certain level of happiness.

H: A/B/C/D/E/F/G

The far left (A) is miserable and is therefore bright red. The far right (G) is ecstatic and is therefore bright green.

Heres a link to the developers forum page on this plugin: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=123279.msg4066368#msg4066368